# Platform 'Android' referenced in the project file 'san-angeles' cannot be found

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, ant

i was trying to run the "San-angeles" example of Visual Studio 2010 and Android so when i double-clicked the .sln file i got 2 warnings :

**1)** C:\vs-android_samples\san-angeles\san-angeles.vcxproj : warning  : Platform 'Android' referenced in the project file 'san-angeles' cannot be found. Please make sure you have it installed under '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\Android'.

**2)** C:\vs-android_samples\san-angeles\san-angeles.vcxproj : error  :  Platform 'Android' referenced in the project file 'san-angeles' cannot be found. Please make sure you have it installed under '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\Android'. The project cannot be loaded.

and nothing is loaded ....

i have :

- VS 2010 - c:/program files
- Android ndk r7 - c:/
- apache ant 1.8.2 - c:/
- Android Samples "San-Angeles" - c:/

am i missing something here ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am i missing something here ?!!

Yes, you're missing the error which explains where it's looking for the vcxproj file...

> Please make sure you have it installed under '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\Android'.

It seems you have two choices - either change the location of the "San-Angeles" example to match whatever path the `%VCTargetsPath%` envar is set to or change that envar to point at the path where you have the sample installed.

Comment: i got all the folders in the same place ...
what else can i do to get the (San-angeles) in the right place ....?

Comment: "i got all the folders in the same place ..." - What does that mean? Have you opened a command prompt and used SET to see what the environment variable `VCTargetsPath` is set to? Alternatively, have you looked at the project settings in VS2010 to see what it's set to?

Comment: thanx for help
i got this figured out

Comment: OK, glad to be of some help. Good luck.